# "Device connection string is not correct." Error - Azure IoT-Hub

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Attempting the "[Connect Raspberry Pi to Azure IoT Hub (Python)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-python-get-started)" tutorial, which worked just fine this morning, but now am getting error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/iot-hub-python-raspberrypi-client-app $ python app.py HostName=RPiHub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=MyPi;SharedAccessKey=Rd++cewght3xMyzpzKeQkKIUxwLokI5BQpvanXYntXE=

Device connection string is not correct.
```

This is when I am attempting to simply run the application.

Code that checks for this error within app.py:

```
def is_correct_connection_string():
    m = re.search("HostName=.*;DeviceId=.*;", CONNECTION_STRING)
    if m:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Tutorial says the string should be "your Azure IoT hub device connection string'", which I am getting from exactly where the tutorial says to get it from.

Strange as this all worked fine earlier, but now trying to do it again on a new Pi it is just refusing to work.

I deleted all the contents in my Azure portal, all the resources etc., to try from scratch. Is there something I missed or leftover that could be causing this?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue with following my below reply?If there is any issue, feel free let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the quotation marks to the device connection string in the command.

```
python app.py "{Device Connection String}"
```

If not, the **CONNECTION_STRING** would be like following.

```
HostName=*.azure-devices.net
```